# Why does Databricks Connect Test not work on Mac?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I've gone through the documentation for configuring `databricks-connect` but still get the error below when running `databricks-connect test`

**Errors From Terminal**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.STRING_REDACTION_PATTERN()Lorg/apache/spark/internal/config/ConfigEntry;
error: not found: value spark import spark.implicits._
error: not found: value spark import spark.sql
error: not found: value spark spark.range(100).reduce(_ + _)
Scala command failed to produce correct result
```

**Steps Used to Setup Databricks Connect**

- Created a cluster on Databricks with Runtime of 5.3 and Python 2
- Set Spark Config to `spark.databricks.service.server.enabled true` **(Restarted)**
- Created Python project using Pyenv and Python `2.7.15`
- Removed pyspark `pip uninstall pyspark`
- Installed Databricks Connect `pip install -U databricks-connect==5.3.*`
- Configured databricks connect `databricks-connect configure`

  - Databricks Host: `https://<account>.cloud.databricks.com`
  - Databricks Token: `<secret_token>`
  - Cluster ID: `<cluster_token>`
  - Org ID: `<left_blank>`
  - Port: `15001`

> What is causing this error and is there a possible fix?

**Used Resources**

- [Databricks DB Connect](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dev-tools/db-connect.html)
- [Databricks Connect Finally](https://datathirst.net/blog/2019/3/7/databricks-connect-finally)
- [Why DB Connect doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55951981/why-databricks-connect-test-does-not-work-after-configurate-databricks-connect)

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, I found another [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40390994/3356901) post that discusses how the Java error hints to a version mismatch. I downgraded my Databricks cluster runtime to 5.1 and updated `databricks-connect` by running:

```
pip install -U databricks-connect==5.1.*
```

To validate, I ran:

```
databricks-connect test
```

Important items to remember:

1. Uninstall pyspark first because installing databricks-connect will install a slightly modified version of pyspark.
2. The databricks-connect version must match the cluster's DBR version.
3. The Python version of your local environment must match the Python version of your cluster. [E.g. 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7,...]

Comment: You do not need to run pip install pyspark.

Comment: @simon_dmorias, this solution works without having pyspark installed on my machine.